# How do I execute a .sh file without opening up a new terminal?

Tags: bash, shell, git-bash

I have a couple of .sh files that I need to execute from within Terminal for the moment, they all individually make up an app. Example of one: `gnome-terminal --command="./batterysim.sh"`.

Is there any way I can execute these without the 'gnome terminal' function? I have tried the 'nohup &' function, which is successful in not opening up another terminal, but the data which the .sh file holds does not then appear in the app. Needless to say I am very new to this.

Comment: When you reference your writeout file in the gnome-terminal --command="./batterysim.sh, do you give the full file path or just the short version? (/foo/bar/file.file or just file.file) I had a similar problem before where && would only record if the full file name/location path was there.

Comment: Why doesn't just `./batterysim.sh` work? Why do you think you need `gnome-terminal` *or* `nohup` or any other such thing? (`nohup` in particular does nothing at all you couldn't do without it using only shell builtins; `somecommand </dev/null >somecommand.log 2>&1 & disown $!` will do everything nohup will do with only functionality built into the shell).

Comment: (Also, "does not then appear in the app" strongly implies that there are critical details being elided here. *How* exactly is this script supposed to be interacting with a different app? Which app? Etc).

Comment: Do you have a hashbang at the start of the script? e.g. `#!/bin/bash`? If not, and it is a shell file, you can use `bash ./batterysim.sh`.

Comment: @halfer if you want to do run the script directly (with the hashbang added), you also need to set the `x-flag`, i.e. `chmod u+x ./batterysim.sh`.